# Including <SELECT> in a query with a search field

Tags: php, mysql, input, filter

I have this form to get user input:

```
<form method="post" action="do_search.php">
    <select name="stat">
        <option value="-">No StatTrak</option>
        <option value="ST">StatTrak</option>
    </select>
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search_box" class="search_box" placeholder="Bayonet / Blue Steel (Factory New)"></br>
        <input type="submit" value="Find item!" class="search_button" /><br />
</form>
```

The query works and searches the second column (itemname) for matches. Now I want to make the select box filter out the results by using the first column.

First column only contains either "ST" or "-".

Here is my query:

```
$search=$_POST['search'];
$stat=$_POST['stat'];
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT itemname, itemprice, itemupdate, itemstat FROM pricedata WHERE itemname Like ? ORDER BY itemprice DESC LIMIT 15");
$query->bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

Basically I need something like:

```
...FROM pricedata where itemname LIKE $Searchbox AND itemstat LIKE $Selectbox...
```

I am new to php and I made this query using some tutorials. I understand most of it, but I don't understand how the values are "prepared".

This part is hard to understand for me:

```
$query->bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

What would be the proper way to make the select box give an additional variable to the query, so it only shows results that match the searchbox AND have either "ST" or "-" in the first column.

Thanks in advance, i appreciate any help! :)

Edit - Here is a part of my Database:
[image]

---

**For Dimlucas:**

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT itemname, itemprice, itemupdate, itemstat FROM pricedata WHERE itemname Like ? AND itemstat=? ORDER BY itemprice DESC LIMIT 15");
$query->bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(2, $stat);
$query->execute();
```

This query (the first one you posted just said "nothing found", but it WOULD do the right thing, if it worked, since it includes both user inputs (select box AND search bar).

```
SELECT itemname, itemprice, itemupdate, itemstat FROM pricedata WHERE itemname Like 'Karambit' AND itemstat='ST' ORDER BY itemprice DESC LIMIT 15
```

I replaced the first one with this one to test, if there is any problem finding the right match. It found the right match, but this one doesn't include any placeholders or user inputs, so I guess, that there is a probleme between taking the user input and giving it to the query to use.

Right now I have this as query and to print out results -> http://pastebin.com/xMf4jCgH

I tried to add $search and $stat in front of the table. It prints out the search string but Neither a "-" or a "ST", which is the input from the select box. So the problem is, that the user input doesn't even reach the query.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Well code `where itemname LIKE $Searchbox AND itemstat LIKE $Selectbox` it looks good to me. Experimenting is the best way of learning

Comment: You can code any number of `$query->bindValue()` so `$query->bindValue(2,"%$select%", PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: Hey and thanks! What does the PDO::PARAM_STR do? And how does the query know, which number is which "?". Is it in ascending order? Does bindvalue(1 mean, that its the first "?" in the query and bindvalue(2, that it's the second one?

Comment: Yes the 1 and 2 mean the first `?` and second `?` `PDO::PARAM_STR` tells `PDO` to treat this param as a string [When all else fails, there is always the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can read about Prepared Statements [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). They are very useful in preventing SQL Injection attacks.

Now for what you want to achieve I suggest you modify the query like so:

```
    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT itemname, itemprice, itemupdate, itemstat FROM pricedata WHERE itemname Like ? AND itemstat=? ORDER BY itemprice DESC LIMIT 15");
    $query->bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(2, $stat);
    $query->execute();
```

**EDIT:** Since you're saying that the stat field can only take two distinct values there is no need to use the `LIKE` operator in your query. The `=` operator will do

Comment: 1+ Neat, haven't heard about this until now

Comment: Hey and thanks, I copied the exact code you posted, but it doesn't give ANY result now. Any idea?

Comment: Include a snapshot of your database in your original post so that I can observe the contents. Note that the database must contain the exact same values for the 'itemstat' column. If the $stat variable contains the value 'ST' but the database column has 'st' it won't work

Comment: I added a part of the database.

Comment: Try running this query:
SELECT itemname, itemprice, itemupdate, itemstat FROM pricedata WHERE itemname Like 'Karambit' AND itemstat='ST' ORDER BY itemprice DESC LIMIT 15

on your MySQL server and see if it prints any results. Also include the code that prints the data received from the database

Comment: That query worked. It found a "ST Karambit", even though that was a bit lucky, because it was looking for ONLY "Karambit" and not entries including karambit. Luckily there is one entrie that is ONLY "Karambit". I also tried another entry, which worked too. Here is a bit more of my code: http://pastebin.com/rWnu6xnE

Comment: If you want it to search for values including Karambit you can wrap the search string in % like this:
 SELECT itemname, itemprice, itemupdate, itemstat FROM pricedata WHERE itemname Like '%Karambit%' AND itemstat='ST' ORDER BY itemprice DESC LIMIT 15

Are you sure that the pastebin code works? You are calling bindValue without any placeholders in the query

Comment: Of course not. The query was only a test like the query you sent me above with the Karambit value and without any placeholders. Tge first query that you sent me in your original code didn't give any results, what was going wrong there? I mean, I am not planning to only look for Karambits and entries with an "ST". I need to have the searchbar and the select box both as variables that are used in the query. What would be the right query, if the one in your original answer did not work (because that would be the right one). :(

Comment: You said above that the query worked when you executed it directly on the MySQL server. So there is probably nothing wrong with the query. Try printing $stat to make sure it gets the user's choice correctly

Comment: It seems like there was a bit of misunderstanding here (I am not a native English speaker). I edited my original post to give some better formatted information. (Check the end of my post). Thanks a lot for your patience!

Comment: So the user's input never reaches the $stat variable. I though so. That's weird considering that you get the value from $_POST. Is your HTML code still the same?

Comment: Oh well...I just found something I totally forgot about. There is a script using ajax in the header of the html file. The form is still the one i pasted in my original post. Here is the script, maybe it's keeping back the $stat variable... http://pastebin.com/yPZqaT4H

Comment: If the form is submitted by an AJAX request coming from that script then yes that could be the cause of the problem. I edited your JS code a bit to include the stat value. Check it out here, it might need some modifications on your end until it works properly: http://pastebin.com/SitXTiTu

Comment: Sadly, the variable of $stat still gets lost somewhere. I will try to make it work somehow. Thank you, big help! :)

Comment: Hey, just wanted to give a response regarding the solution. I used the query and script you helped me with and asked a friend who is really good at coding. He told me to add id="stat" to the <select name="stat"> and it worked immediately. Don't know why though. :D

Comment: Yes, it worked because the jquery selector $('#stat') only works with the id attribute in contrast with PHP's $_POST that works with the name attribute of an element

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt seems to be ok:

```
"...FROM pricedata WHERE itemname LIKE ".$Searchbox." AND itemstat LIKE ".$Selectbox.";"
```